# Gerrit rest api returns empty JSONArray to java environment, but returns non empty to the browser

Tags: java, json, api, resteasy, gerrit

I faced following problem: 
I wanna get list of changes from gerrit repository using this api function https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes
When I sent GET request in browser I got response

```
[
 {
  "id": "business~develop~I65d58a2345346cb35a0ecbb63d6ed896c7",
  "project": "business",
  "branch": "develop",
  "hashtags": [],
  "change_id": "I65d58a2a045645636cb35a0ecbb63d6ed896c7",
  "subject": "Leader property deleted from organizational unit classes. Org unit\u0027s employees cascad type removed. Employee\u0027s roles amount limited by 1 in orgUnit.xsd. Employees identifiers changed in orgUnit.xml. Updated domain model. DataUploadRestService created. Emp",
  "status": "NEW",
  "created": "2015-05-12 14:31:48.226000000",
  "updated": "2015-07-07 07:34:35.195000000",
  "mergeable": true,
  "insertions": 3100,
  "deletions": 1358,
  "_number": 589,
  "owner": {
    "_account_id": 1003473
  }
 }
]
```

But when I send GET request using RestEasy or other way to send request using Java code:

```
try {
    final ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    final ResteasyWebTarget target = client
                .target("https://gml-jbpm.gomel.iba.by/gerrit/changes/");
    String response = target.request().get(String.class);
    final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
    System.out.println("RestEasy response: " + array);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get empty response:

```
[]
```

How to solve this problem? Why I get empty JSONArray?

Comment: This is probably because Gerrit returns some magic chars at the begining of the response.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this libary so you do not have to care about JSON: https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-rest-java-client